# Trying to make mutate_at work with strptime

Tags: r, dplyr

I have the following data frame:

```
df = data.frame(date = "23-12-09 22:52")
```

This code works fine:

```
strptime(df$date, "%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
# [1] "2009-12-23 22:52:00 CET"`
```

But if I try it using `mutate_at` I get an error:

```
dplyr::mutate_at(df, vars(date), strptime, "%d-%m-%y %H:%M")
```

> Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
>    Column "date" is of unsupported class POSIXlt`

I would like to understand why my `mutate_at` statement doesn't work. (I don't need an alternative solution. This question is purely educational.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After applying `strptime` class of `date` column becomes `POSIXlt`

```
class(strptime(df$date, "%d-%m-%y %H:%M"))
#[1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"
```

`dplyr` doesn't want to handle objects of class `POSIXlt` because of the reasons mentioned [here](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/179).

So you need to have objects of other class in `dplyr` chain. Maybe a character

```
dplyr::mutate_at(df, vars(date), ~ as.character(strptime(., "%d-%m-%y %H:%M")))

#                 date
#1 2009-12-23 22:52:00
```

Or a `POSIXct` object

```
dplyr::mutate_at(df, vars(date), ~ as.POSIXct(., format = "%d-%m-%y %H:%M"))

#                date
#1 2009-12-23 22:52:00
```

Comment: Thanks. May I know why you use a tilde (~) in front of as.character and as.POSIXct?

Comment: @Frank that is one way to specify a formula style function mostly used in `purrr`.